# How can I make the name of my output file the same as the input one in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am working with files that are named after dates, such as "2020-02-24-16-13.h264". I am trying to get MP4Box to process all of these files in a bash script, but I can't figure out how to name the output files properly.

Essentially, I would like the script to automatically take the name of the .h264 file and output to the same name, with .mp4

The command I am using to do it manually is:

```
MP4Box -add /mnt/usb/Convert/2020-02-24-16-13.h264 /mnt/usb/Converted/2020-02-24-16-13.mp4
```

I cannot switch to `ffmpeg` in my situation as a workaround.

I am very much hoping this is a simple command tweak but any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: and the expected output is?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding you, the expected output is the same exact name as the input file, but instead ending with .mp4. Running this manually per each file works as expected, I would like it to automatically know what to name each output file based off of the input (.h264 file) though.

Comment: Ok, understood, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this.

```
for f in /mnt/usb/Convert/2020-02-24-16-13.h264; do
   echo MP4Box -add "$f" "${f%.*}.mp4"
done
```

output

```
MP4Box -add /mnt/usb/Convert/2020-02-24-16-13.h264 /mnt/usb/Convert/2020-02-24-16-13.mp4
```

If you have a lot of files ending in `*.h264`

```
for f in /mnt/usb/Convert/*.h264; do
   echo MP4Box -add "$f" "${f%.*}.mp4"
done
```

If you're inside `/mnt/usb/Convert` use this.

```
for f in *.h264; do
  echo MP4Box -add "$f" "${f%.*}.mp4"
done
```

To ouput the converted files to the Converted directory,
which the OP's original question 
(sorry for not noticing that.)

```
for f in /mnt/usb/Convert/2020-02-24-16-13.h264; do
  n=${f/Convert/Converted}
  echo MP4Box -add "$f" "${n%.*}.mp4"
done
```

Output.

```
MP4Box -add /mnt/usb/Convert/2020-02-24-16-13.h264 /mnt/usb/Converted/2020-02-24-16-13.mp4
```

To deal with all the files in batch.

```
for f in /mnt/usb/Convert/*.h264; do
  n=${f/Convert/Converted}
  echo MP4Box -add "$f" "${n%.*}.mp4"
done
```

An alternative to the `${string/search/replace}` bash specific P.E.

```
for f in /mnt/usb/Convert/*.h264; do
  n=${f##*Convert}
  m=${f%Convert*}
  echo MP4Box -add "$f" "${m}Converted${n%.*}.mp4";
done
```

The above (last example) is not restricted to bash syntax but should work in any POSIX compliant shell.

- Remove the `echo` if you're satisfied with the output.
- See parameter expansion `PAGER='less +/^[[:space:]]*parameter\ expansion' man bash`

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly. 

Just as one last thing, how would I change it to output to /Converted instead of /Convert if i'm executing from my home directory?

Comment: I have updated the answer, sorry for not noticing that the output directory is different from the input.

Comment: No problem at all! My naming scheme isn't the best either quite honestly. Ill try the new fix out as soon as I get the chance. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: I'm using the very last for statement in your post under "To deal with all the files in batch", and it seems to be giving me the same output as before so far. Using echo to see the output shows that the mp4 files are still outputting to the "Convert" directory. If it helps clarify anything, my Converted and Convert folders have the same parent directory.

Comment: The echo output has the same directory? It does work on my example yes?

Comment: The `n=${f/Convert/Converted}` should deal with that situation/requirement. Which means change the srting `Convert`  to `Converted`. You're using `bash` and not other shell right?

Comment: I am using bash, I tried changing around Convert and Converted throughout the code, but it didn't seem to change the output directory. For the sake of a less lengthy comment, here is a pastebin of my code and output: https://pastebin.com/zyGRsU4s

Comment: `echo MP4Box -add "$f" "${f%.*}.mp4"` It is not included on my last `for-loop` please check again, I mean second to the last `for-loop`

Comment: Ah my apologies, I missed the "n". Now both of those two solutions you suggested work perfectly. Thank you once again, you are a life saver.